# How to make auto log out when idle?

Tags: java, swing

I made a java swing application. Now I want to make it auto log out when user is idle.

Is there any way to detect 'idle' in java swing? I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Can you define 'ideal'?

Comment: Sorry, I mean idle. Sorry for the mistake.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [Application Inactivity](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/24/application-inactivity/) for one approach.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know how to define a Action :
Action logout = new YourLogoutAction(...);

Comment: @KalanaSarange, I made a change to the InactivityListener so you will need to download the source code again. I also added a simple example of a logout Action to the blog page.

Answer (score 0):

in swing you can use `System.exit(0);` to kill your window in any case. In your case I am guessing that you want to logout after a definite time delay then for that you can use thread with your code.